# Running USSD on the background android

Tags: java, android

I have this code that performs a **USSD** call.

```
String ussdCode = "*" + "914"+"%23";
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
```

Is there a way I can run the above `command` on the background or on the `console` instead of running it as a dial on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

USSD call interuptn is not yet supported n Android

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285

API support is not available for Call and CallBack. For now it is Sync call which opens PORT on client and server and do the communication.

Comment: Show me what you mean by Sync call.